# How do I move this controller code to a Resque job?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I want to move some of my sessions controller process into a Resque worker to make logging in much smoother. I want to move parts from here:

```
def create  
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth,omniauth)     

  session[:user_id] = user.id  
  session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session['fb_access_token'] = omniauth['credentials']['token']
  session['fb_error'] = nil

  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(current_user.token)
  current_user.profile = @graph.get_object("me")
  current_user.likes = @graph.get_connections("me", "likes")
  current_user.friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
  current_user.save
  redirect_to root_url 
end
```

Into a Resque worker (is it in /tasks?)

```
#ResqueFacebook.rb

require 'resque-retry'
Class FBResque
  def self.perform()
      @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(current_user.token)
      current_user.profile = @graph.get_object("me")
      current_user.likes = @graph.get_connections("me", "likes")
      current_user.friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
      current_user.save
  end    
End
```

What do I add to the sessions controller to initialize that worker job? Also, because it won't exist in the session anymore, current_user will be a nil object. Would that mean the code in the worker would have to be in a for user in User loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to put them in `app/jobs/`, since it's on the autoload path, while `lib` tends to be more of a nuisance (albeit it completely valid).

This should be enough:

```
require 'resque-retry'

class FBConnectionsJob
  @queue = :fb_connections

  def self.perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)  
    graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(user.token)
    user.profile = graph.get_object("me")
    user.likes = graph.get_connections("me", "likes")
    user.friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
    user.save
  end    
end


def create  
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth,omniauth)     

  session[:user_id] = user.id  
  session['fb_auth'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  session['fb_access_token'] = omniauth['credentials']['token']
  session['fb_error'] = nil

  Resque.enqueue(FBConnectionsJob, current_user.id)

  redirect_to root_url 
end
```

PS: Why are you typing `Class` and `End` in uppercase? o_O

Comment: Will give this a shot. Um, not really sure. Whoops. Do you just mind explaining the `fb_connections` symbol please?

Comment: @Simpleton its the name of the queue incase if you haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @Millisami Yep. Hard to grasp how I didn't understand symbols then.